# How do I check for occurrence in two tables simultaneously

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query (oracle) that checks for both persons and firms, the problem is that you won't find a company in the user table and the other way around.

As of now I write this in two queries, but I would like to make this into one query (for example if I can get some help creating a temporay table)

I have a info table that tells me if this is a user, a company or both

The sql looks a bit like this:

```
Table1: 
    fk_id, 
    info1, 
    info2, 
    info3

Info_table: 
    fk_id, 
    <info if user, company or both>

User_table: 
    firstname, 
    lastname, 
    adress, 
    fk_id

Company_table: 
    Companyname, 
    adress, 
    fk_id
```

I would like to eighter 1:

Make a temporary table that looks like this:

```
Temptable: 
    fk_id, 
    firstname(if user or both, else empty), 
    lastname(if user, else companyname), 
    adress
```

or make a query like this:

```
select table1.info1, table1.info2, firstname, lastname, adress 
from table1,
     user_table,
     company_table,
     info_table
where table1.fk_id = user_table.fk_id (if user or both)
   or table1.fk_id = company_table.fk_id (if company)
```

Any tips on how to solve this would be great. What is the best solution (making a temp table or to add this into the initial query)?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: So, I would like to write the code like this: select table1.info, usertable.firstname from table1 join usertable on table1.fk_id = usertable.fk_id ? (I'm not used to writing code with explisit joins)

Comment: Something like that. It's 2019 now, explicit `JOIN`s have been here for almost 30 years. No-one should start learning SQL today using those comma separated, implicit joins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left outer join (in this response i'll use the + operator for convenience)

```
select table1.info1, table1.info2, 
    firstname, 
    nvl(lastname,company_name) lastname, 
    nvl(user_table.adress,company_table.adress) adress 
from table1,
    user_table,
    company_table,
    info_table
where 
    table1.fk_id=info_table.fk_id(+) 
    and table1.fk_id = user_table.fk_id(+) --(if user or both)
    and table1.fk_id = company_table.fk_id(+) --(if company)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union:

quick example:

```
select firstname
      ,lastname as name
      ,'person_table' as source_table
  from person_table
union
select null
      ,company_name
      ,'company_table'
  from company_table;
```

The result will be a list of both persons and companies.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write this query:

```
select t1.info1, t1.info2, ut.firstname, 
       coalesce(ut.lastname, ct.company_name) as lastname, 
       coalesce(ut.adress, ct.adress) as address 
from table1 t1 left join
     info_table it
     on t1.fk_id = it.fk_id left join
     user_table ut
     on t1.fk_id = ut.fk_id and
        it.info in ('both', 'user') left join
     company_table ct
     on t1.fk_id = ct.fk_id and
        ct.info in ('both', 'company') ;
```

Notes:

- This uses proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax, as recommended by Oracle itself.
- This only does the joins when the type specifies that the join is appropriate.
- This uses `COALESCE()`, a standard function, rather than the bespoke `NVL()`.
- All column names are qualified.
- This uses table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.